# What would an instruction in assembly (x86) be that could cause a buffer overflow?

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to get my head around buffers / buffer overflows in assembly language. I understand that if a buffer is created and the data being put into is larger than the buffer, it will overflow.

Given the example of:

`sub esp, 28` - large buffer all the way to ebp

`sub esp, 32` - small buffer from ebp-32 to ebp-28

If more than 4 bytes were entered into `ebp-32` this would overflow into `ebp-28`. I understand that: `mov [ebp-32], ebx` would put a dword into `ebp-32`, but if I wanted to overflow into `ebp-28` all the way to `ebp` I would need a 32*32=1024 bit/128byte string.

How could this be achieved / what would the instruction look like in assembly?  If some form of loop is needed, is it possible without a loop??

Lastly, given my example would the memory to computer just look like `ebp` to `ebp-32`, with it being up to the program to specify it wants to use 32bits at `ebp-32`, or `ebp-16` for example.

Comment: How abour `rep stos`?

Comment: To have a buffer overflow you simply have to write outside allocated memory. This can be achieved in several different manners.

Comment: Please show a simple hex dump of the buffer before and after the overflow.  It would be quite nice to see the registers as well.

Comment: Thank Kerrek, that looks to be exactly what I was after.  This explained the `rep` instruction nicely, for anyone else interested. [link](http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/csbsju/cs/350/handouts/x86.html)

Comment: @User.1 , I used GDB to view the registers after a buffer overflow, using `info registers`.  Indeed, it is interesting.

Comment: @Soap  Post some screen caps; if it's text you might/should/may/possibly be able to do an old fashioned cut and paste here.  Let us see the memory in question, and the X-Number of instructions leading up to the buffer overflow.  p.s., how do you know the buffer overflowed ?

Comment: @User.1 Okay, I haven't chance atm, but basically I inputted a longer string than the allocated buffer (I used strcpy and printf), and then I could see ebp being overwritten with my random string, then it continued to overflow into eip.